# How to connect to Laravel Websocket with React?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, websocket, pusher

I'm building an ordering app, where I do the backend with `Laravel` and the front end with both `ReactJS` and `React Native`

I want real-time updates whenever a customer posts an order and whenever an order gets updated.

Currently, I managed to get WebSocket running that uses the pusher API [using devmarketer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUpZlSbGs9M&list=LLsp3HnBJLGuAj8dqMtEl7Jw&index=6&t=603s) his tutorial.

I'm successful in echoing the order in the console, but now I want to access the `channel` using my `react` app

And at this step is where I am facing difficulties.

As I'm unsure how to create a `route` that is accessible to both my apps and how to access the channel through this route.

The official laravel documentation gives an example of how to access pusher but not how to connect to it with for example an outside connection (example: my react native app)

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'rapio1',
  host: 'http://backend.rapio',
  authEndpoint: 'http://backend.rapio/broadcasting/auth',
  auth: {
    headers: {
      // Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  }
  // encrypted: true
});
window.Echo.channel('rapio.1').listen('OrderPushed', (e) =>{
    console.log(e.order)
})
```

So my question is how can I access a broadcasting channel on my `React` apps?

**ADDED BACKEND EVENT**

```
class OrderPushed implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $neworder;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $neworder)
    {
        $this->neworder = $neworder;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        //return new Channel('Rapio.'.$this->neworder->id);
       return new Channel('Rapio');

    }
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'status' => $this->neworder->status,
            'user' => $this->neworder->user->id,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to get access to your Echo variable in your entire components?

Comment: No, I want to acces it on one component in each app (react and react native)

Comment: Are you getting any specific error? I'm wondering if your issue is related to the CSRF token. When using **Echo** with the Laravel front end, the lib may get the token from meta tags. Maybe it's worth trying to add the `csrfToken` param to the constructor. Take a look a the source [here](https://github.com/laravel/echo/blob/6b71473266b08f66be929df26336f6cd62fbd3ea/src/connector/connector.ts#L48).

Comment: Also, I'd try to remove the host from `authEndpoint` param. This way: `authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',`.

Comment: I actually tried with and without csrfToken, but no difference. I also don't get any kind of error message. It works within my `welcom.blade` page but not on my separate react site. Which is crucial because after I want it to work on my react native app

Comment: @GustavoStraube I've also tried your suggestion, but still no resolve :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using the `broadcastAs()` method on the backend?

It's important to know this in order to answer your question properly because if you are, the Laravel echo client assumes that the namespace is App\OrderPushed.

When using `broadcastAs()` you need to prefix it with a dot, to tell `echo` not to use the namespacing so in your example, it would be:

`.listen('.OrderPushed')`

Also, you don't need to do any additional setup on the backend in order for each client application to connect to the socket server unless you want to have a multi-tenancy setup whereby different backend applications will make use of the WebSockets server.

I also use `wsHost` and `wsPort` instead of just host and port, not sure if that makes a difference though

Comment: I'm using `broadcastWith()`  I've added my event

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the data on the frontend by simply `console.log`'ing to the console you should already be most of the way there.

The way you would actually get the data into your react components depends on if you're using a state management library (such as redux) or just pure react.

Basically, you would maintain a local copy of the data on the frontend and then use the Echo events to update that data. For example, you could have a list of orders in either redux, one of your react components, or somewhere else, that you could append to and modify based on creation, update, and deletion events.

I would personally create an `OrderCreated`, `OrderUpdated`, and  `OrderDeleted` event on the backend that would contain the given order model.

```js
class OrdersList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchInitialDataUsingHttp();

        //Set up listeners when the component is being mounted
        window.Echo.channel('rapio.1').listen('OrderCreated', (e) =>{
            this.addNewOrder(e.order);
        }).listen('OrderUpdated', (e) =>{
            this.updateOrder(e.order);
        }).listen('OrderDeleted', (e) =>{
            this.removeOrder(e.order);
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        //@TODO: Disconnect echo
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is I'm not getting any feedback from the backend yet. I still need to maintain a connection with the backend